# Access nested array items in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the javascript trivia API to make an application. I'm having issues displaying each of the values of the wrong answer.

So far I have saved them in my state, along with the questions, and the correct answer

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50').then(response => {
    for (var key in response.data.results) {
      console.log(response.data.results[key].question)
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        questions: [...prevState.questions, response.data.results[key].question],
        answers: [...prevState.answers, response.data.results[key].correct_answer],
        wrongAnswers: [...prevState.wrongAnswers, response.data.results[key].incorrect_answers]

      }));
    }
  });
}
```

this works fine, but my issue is that the wrong answers is an array itself, so whenever I display the state

```
<p>{this.state.wrongAnswers[this.state.random]}</p> // prints array of strings
```

I get another array, and I can access each element using the dot operator, because I don't know the answers since the questions are chosen randomly.

I want to display the values dynamically using radio buttons. Is there a way to access each element of the nested array and display them dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through that array and show the wrong answers

```
{Array.isArray(this.state.wrongAnswers) && this.state.wrongAnswers.map((wrongAnswer, index) => {
  <p key={'Key-'+index}>wrongAnswer}</p>
}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though I'm looking to display the values inside a radio button :D

Comment: The answer is good but main thing missing is key to the p element. If you don’t add key then only one p element will be rendered. A key can be unique id of each object from data or index. But preferably use unique id as key