# can't access index of Array in ReactJS state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting some information from a trivia app and setting my state respectively.

```
componentDidMount(){
axios.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50').then( response =>{
for(var key in response.data.results){
this.setState( prevState => ({
    questions: [...prevState.questions, response.data.results[key].question],
    answers: [...prevState.answers, response.data.results[key].correct_answer],
    wrongAnswers: [...prevState.wrongAnswers, response.data.results[key].incorrect_answers]

 }));    
}
 });
}
```

NOTE: questions, is a string and so is answer, however, wrongAnswers is an array.

whenever I try to render wrongAnswers inside my jsx code the data is displayed as it should. However, whenever I try to access an index or map the elements of the array, I get an error, saying its undefined. I figured it might have something to do, with the fact, that I get the data synchronized in componentDidmount, so I made a check in the render method to see what was displayed.

```
console.log(this.state.wrongAnswers[this.state.random]);
```

the first render i get undefined but, since then every time the UI updates i get the correct array displayed, if i put this into my jsx code, the array is also displayed like it should.

However i want to map the wrongAnswers to radio buttons like such

```
               {this.state.wrongAnswers[this.state.random].map((wrongAnswer, index) => {
  <p key={'Key-'+index}>{wrongAnswer}</p>
      })}
     <form action="">
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value={wrongAnswer} /> 
   Male<br/>
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value={wrongAnswer}/> 
   Female<br/>
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value={wrongAnswer}/> 
   Other<br/>
     </form>
```

Comment: You need to compose all the objects you want in your state, then call `setState` once. (setState is asynchronous, calling it 50 times like that is bound to give some unexpected results)

Comment: Why are you posting same question again? This one already resolves your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571215/access-nested-array-items-in-javascript/53571278#53571278

Comment: @HemadriDasari The first solution improved The code but did not solve The problem i still get undefined as of now

Comment: If first solution didn’t work then you should comment and explain to one who answered your question about the issue rather than posting as a separate question. Also if answer didn’t resolve the issue then please don’t accept it as verified answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access nested array items in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571215/access-nested-array-items-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all i would suggest you to to make your state merging first and then call setState() once. Imagine if you have amount=50 then your App will update itself 50 times before the final result is shown.

Second advice is put a condition before you render the data from your state to ensure that your state's list is not undefined at the time of rendering.

```
class Component React.Component {
  state= {
    random: someValue,
    questions: [],
    answers: [],
    wrongAnswers: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Your api logic
    // merge and prepare new state object before calling this.setState() !!
    const newObject = mergeLogic();
    // then setState to execute update just once
    this.setState({wrongAnswers: newObject})
  }

  render() {
    const {random, wrongAnswers } = this.state;

    return (
      {wrongAnswers && wrongAnswers[random].map((wrongAnswer, index) => {
        <p key={'Key-'+index}>{wrongAnswer}</p>
      })}

     // your other code...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So i should save all my logic in an object before setting the state?

Comment: I would suggest you to do so. The code above is just showcase I see that you have there `answers` and `questions` arrays too but its not fun to write a code from mobile... :D

Comment: Just remember to keep the number of udpates as low as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much! this is great!

Comment: glad to help. Good luck!